# How We can mock test multiple api calls in jest testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I have a scenario like i have to call 1stAPI then depending on the response of 1st API i have to call 2nd API.

I got a solution to test 1st API :

```js
global.fetch = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation(() => getMockPromise({ Response: resMock }));
```

I got my 1st response while mocking
but how can I get response in second ? I am using typescript with react

I tried to search multiple places but only got solution for one mock response only for jest testing like below :

```js
global.fetch = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation(() => getMockPromise({ Response: resMock }));
```

I thought if I use the above `mockImplementation` two times for different response it will work, but still same only one is working.

Comment: From the sound of it, you may be looking for `mockImplementationOnce`? But also wondering if the below answer works for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling `fetch()` with different arguments each time, you can use a mock implementation that responds with different data depending on the argument it receives.

```
//test file
const mockedResponses = {
  'firstUrl': {}, // first response object
  'secondUrl': {}, // second response object
}

global.fetch = jest
  .fn()
  .mockImplementation((url: string) => getMockPromise({ Response: mockedResponses[url] }));
```

Generally it's a good idea to have the actual `fetch()` call be done inside a separate function, e.g. `callFirstApi()` and `callSecondApi()`, and then you can just mock those functions instead. This also means you don't end up overwriting a global function.

You can also look into something like the Nock package which lets you do more elaborate testing of external APIs.